# Assign specific nominal values randomly to rows using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to assign some selected nominal values randomly to rows. For example: 
I have three nominal values `["apple", "orange", "banana"]`.
Before assign these values randomly to rows:

```
**Name         Fruit**    
Jack              
Julie              
Juana              
Jenny              
Christina          
Dickens            
Robert             
Cersei
```

After assign these values randomly to rows:

```
**Name               Fruit**
Jack               Apple
Julie              Orange
Juana              Apple
Jenny              Banana
Christina          Orange
Dickens            Orange
Robert             Apple
Cersei             Banana
```

How can I do this using pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with your values:

```
vals = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]

df['Fruit'] = pd.np.random.choice(vals, len(df))

>>> df
        Name   Fruit
0       Jack   apple
1      Julie  orange
2      Juana   apple
3      Jenny  orange
4  Christina   apple
5    Dickens  banana
6     Robert  orange
7     Cersei  orange
```

Comment: you don't need `pd` in `pd.np.random.choice()`

Comment: It avoids explicitly importing `numpy`, as it's packaged in with `pandas` :)

Comment: Try it without importing numpy and without the pd and see if it works.

Comment: As I thought, you get `NameError: name 'np' is not defined`

Comment: Super weird, I asked because I just restarted my terminal and cleared imports and it worked fine. Better leave it then!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a DataFrame in pandas and then assign random choices using numpy

```
ex2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jack','Julie','Juana','Jenny','Christina','Dickens','Robert','Cersei']})

ex2['Fruits'] = np.random.choice(['Apple','Orange','Banana'],ex2.shape[0])
```